# Effective and comfortable way to return link to an object of array in array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
let array = [{
    'a': 1,
    'b': [{
        'c': 1,
        'd': 2
    }, {
        'c': 3,
        'd': 4
    }]
}, {
    'a': 3,
    'b': [{
        'c': 5,
        'd': 6
    }, {
        'c': 7,
        'd': 8
    }]
}, {
    'a': 5,
    'b': [{
        'c': 9,
        'd': 10
    }, {
        'c': 11,
        'd': 12
    }]
}];
```

I need find the object that includes value "9" in property "c" and change it to "88". I used code like this:

```
const toFindValue = 9

const result = array.filter(f1 =>
                                f1.b.some(v =>
                                              v.c === toFindValue))
                    .map(f2 =>
                             f2.b.filter(f3 =>
                                             f3.c === toFindValue))
                    .flat(Infinity)[0];

result.c = 88;

array.forEach(v => console.log(v))
```

```js
let array = [{
  'a': 1,
  'b': [{
    'c': 1,
    'd': 2
  }, {
    'c': 3,
    'd': 4
  }]
}, {
  'a': 3,
  'b': [{
    'c': 5,
    'd': 6
  }, {
    'c': 7,
    'd': 8
  }]
}, {
  'a': 5,
  'b': [{
    'c': 9,
    'd': 10
  }, {
    'c': 11,
    'd': 12
  }]
}];
const toFindValue = 9

const result = array.filter(f1 =>
    f1.b.some(v =>
      v.c === toFindValue))
  .map(f2 =>
    f2.b.filter(f3 =>
      f3.c === toFindValue))
  .flat(Infinity)[0];

result.c = 88;

array.forEach(v => console.log(v))
```

But I'm not sure this is the most efficient way.

The StackOverflow filter is too aggressive and does not allow editing question that reformats code w/o adding a massive amount of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.some` nested in a `filter`, and the other `filter` nested in a `map` followed by `flat` is a bit complicated. I think it'd be easier to just iterate over the `b` array, and reassign the `c` property of the object if it's equal to the `toFindValue`:

```
const toFindValue = 9;
outer:
for (const { b } of array) {
  for (const obj of b) {
    if (obj.c === toFindValue) {
      obj.c = 88;
      break outer;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
let array = [{
    'a': 1,
    'b': [{
        'c': 1,
        'd': 2
    }, {
        'c': 3,
        'd': 4
    }]
}, {
    'a': 3,
    'b': [{
        'c': 5,
        'd': 6
    }, {
        'c': 7,
        'd': 8
    }]
}, {
    'a': 5,
    'b': [{
        'c': 9,
        'd': 10
    }, {
        'c': 11,
        'd': 12
    }]
}];

const toFindValue = 9;
outer:
for (const { b } of array) {
  for (const obj of b) {
    if (obj.c === toFindValue) {
      obj.c = 88;
      break outer;
    }
  }
}
console.log(array);
```

It's less functional, but it requires fewer operations and is a lot easier to understand.

(if there may be more than one object to change, and you want to change them all, remove the `outer` label and the `break`)

Comment: @deni5n : I guess, it is worth mentioning explicitly (for future readers) that initial code and accepted answer both assume there's an unique item, having `c=9`. Otherwise, it will skip the matches except the first one.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov if they really are "readers", they should be able to read the last line, which mentions what to do if `c=9` is not unique and how not to skip matches :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the first one which matches `toFindValue`, `Array.prototype.find` can be a better method:

```js
array.find(v => v.b.some(e => e.c === toFindValue))
  .b
  .find(e => e.c === toFindValue)
  .c = 88
```

And of course, you should pay attention to `undefined` error.

Comment: Above will loop twice over `b` (with `some()` and then with `find()`), when finds a match, so it doesn't look that much efficient. Besides, it will change only first occurrence of `c=9`, it `b` holds multiple items, having  `c=9`, it will ignore them except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

A two loops (for outer keys) and then nested arrays is the most efficient way that I can think of, which should beat the OP's 5-loops.

The following assumptions are made:

1. `b` is a key that exists in each set
2. `c` is a key that exists in `b` and only in `b`

Given that, I've added some more values where c==9 and they all turn to 88.  Kudos to object destructuring-assignment for keeping this clean:

```js
const array = getData()
const toFindValue = 9;
const toSetValue = 88;

array.forEach(({b}) => {
  b.forEach(({c},i) => {
    if (c == toFindValue)
      b[i].c = toSetValue;
  })
})

array.forEach(v => console.log(v))


/**************************************************************************/

function getData() {
  return [{
      'a': 1,
      'b': [{
        'c': 1,
        'd': 2
      }, {
        'c': 3,
        'd': 4
      }]
    },
    {
      'a': 3,
      'b': [{
        'c': 5,
        'd': 6
      }, {
        'c': 7,
        'd': 8
      }]
    },
    {
      'a': 5,
      'b': [{
        'c': 9,
        'd': 10
      }, {
        'c': 11,
        'd': 12
      }]
    },
    {
      'a': 7,
      'b': [{
        'c': 9,
        'd': 13
      }, {
        'c': 9,
        'd': 14
      }]
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh !important; }
```